# Как отключить сессию для модуля yii2

Tags: php, yii2, rest

yii2-advanced, разрабатываю restful-api как модуль для основного приложения.

можно ли как-то отключить сессию для конкретного модуля? и если можно, то как?

пробовал так, не работает (метод класса модуля):

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
    \Yii::$app->user->enableAutoLogin = false;
}
```

для всего приложения отключить сессию не могу.

PS Вообще можно ли делать так, как в предложеном мною ответе? Есть ли более адекватные варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так в модели модуля:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    Yii::$app->user->logout();
    Yii::$app->session->destroy();
    // custom initialization code goes here
}
```

Comment: Ох, сейчас налетят любители сказать, что это не ответ, а часть вопроса ))

Comment: @AK, это решило мою проблему, и я как бы ответил на свой вопрос. разве нет? да и я не сразу так решил сделать, а через некоторое время после возникновения проблемы.

Comment: @AK Может так лучше, чтобы избежать комментариев "это не ответ", а то и минусов?